# Ubuntu 14.04 mouse pointer numpad slow

Tags: mouse, numpad

I intend to use the numpad as the mouse. It's working, but the movement of the mouse is impractically slow.

Can anyone tell me how to increase the speed of the mouse pointer using when using the numpad?

I understand that in System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad I can alter the speed of the mouse pointer when using the mouse. But that leaves the "nunmpad" mouse speed unaffected.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Workaround

Found on google after visiting this question.

It's a hack but worked on my 14.04.

Install `xkbset`

```
sudo apt-get install xkbset
```

Open a terminal and run

```
watch -n 1 xkbset ma 60 10 10 5 10
```

Comment: This is ghastly. Why to run every second?

Comment: This still works in 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so i created tool : [reachIt](https://github.com/ashishnegi/reachit)

Binaries are at : [ubuntu_release](https://github.com/ashishnegi/reachit/tree/master/bin/linux/release)

It divides the screen into multiple boxes recursively so that you can reach the location faster.

[image: Demo Usage]

Any constructive feedback is appreciated. It is also available on windows.

Comment: Nice work Man (y)